# Yoga 2 13 (Not Pro) 'Bricked' WiFi

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, ideapad, yoga-2

Stop! This isn't a duplicate - but it may also not be completely Ubuntu

As described https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Yoga-2-13-not-Pro-Linux-Warning/td-p/1491698 , trying to install Ubuntu on a non-pro Yoga bricks wifi. I did not realise this before installing. Ergo I have bricked wifi.

I have no other way of connecting this machine to the internet through Ubuntu - I can use a USB dongle within Windows but this isn't working in Ubuntu.

The question is, how to follow the necessary steps from the above forum without internet? Can I flip the bits that are blocking WiFi from Windows? Or from within Ubuntu before I download kernel source? Can I compile somewhere else and copy over? If so, how do I make sure everything is right?

Comment: Did you try: sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop? Any change?

Comment: I used `sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop` and then rfkill unblock... No success any of the times I tried it. Remember, Wifi has also been blocked within Windows too - the forum above suggests that linux has written some bits telling everyone to turn off wifi.

Comment: I am well acquainted with the problem. Please see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215044&highlight=yoga I am looking for the easiest solution and will propose an answer in a few moments.

Comment: Thank you! Obviously the hardest part of this problem is that I want to avoid going and buying a USB-Ethernet cable - otherwise I could have followed any of the previous instructions (although with difficulty!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot but it may work well enough. Apparently, it only needs to be run once. Please download this from my personal Dropbox. These are the files I compiled in connection with the forum thread I linked: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7436581/ideapad2.zip Drag and drop the file to the desktop of the Yoga. Right-click and select 'Extract Here.' Make sure the module in the kernel is unloaded:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
```

Now load the experimental version I compiled:

```
cd ~/Desktop/ideapad2
sudo modprobe sparse-keymap
sudo insmod ideapad-laptop.ko
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
sudo rmmod ideapad-laptop.ko
```

Look for errors, warnings and wireless activity! If you encounter the 'unknown symbol' again, you may need the kernel headers matching your kernel. Go here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic Download and install the 64-bit package. Then try the commands above once more.

If successful, blacklist the original module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

WARNING: This fix may only work for kernel version 3.13.0-32-generic and 64-bit.

Comment: I'm sorry mate - it gives the error `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ideapad-laptop.ko: Unknown symbol in module`

Comment: I installed 14.04 LTS if that helps. But honestly, I wasn't expecting anyone to compile it for me! Thank you so much for going that extra!

Comment: What is your kernel version? uname -r and also: arch Thanks.

Comment: `3.13.0-32-generic` and `x86_64` respectively

Comment: I will try another way in a couple of hours.

Comment: (maybe I can get some sleep then!) Thank you, again, for your help.

Comment: Please see my edit above using ideapad2.zip.

Comment: I have exactly the same error message... no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19539/discussion-between-drnessie-and-chili555).

Comment: Please see my edit above.